# How to wrap text in autocomplete field - Primefaces 6.2.8

Tags: css, primefaces

If Autocomplete item text length is large, I am unable see the cross icon (token) to delete. Please guide how to wrap text if the text length is too large?

[image: Please click here for image attached]

Comment: By using CSS, like you tagged? That is at least what I would try (after preventing long autcomplete strings) And version info should only be in the title if it e.g. worked with PrimeFaces 6.2.7 and is a regression. Otherwise only mention it in the question

Comment: @kukeltje : Thank you for the information provided. I tried with different css techniques but nothing worked. For example: I added word-wrap: break-word; on .ui-autocomplete (did not work).

Comment: Css works on html, so of you esit your question and post the  genertated html of this compoment and tag it html, many can help you. And please edit the question regarding the title.And also post what you tried in there